# Azure ADO Build + deploy to azure web app still showing "welcome node developers" page

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am having an issue when creating a build in ADO that deploys code to an Azure Web App. I can log in to azure and see that the files were copied over to the `/site/wwwroot/` folder but I'm still seeing the default "Hey, Node developers!" page.

For what its worth the app that is being built and deployed is an angular 8 application. The files that were copied to the wwwroot folder are as follow

[image]

publish step

[image]

I'm not sure exactly what is wrong here. I've tried to deploy from VS Code as well but with the same results.

Comment: Can you show your settings of your publish step?

Comment: yes added the publish step from ADO above.

Comment: Updated my answer now as this seems to be a linux app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if hostingstart is above your own welcome page in the default documents section, looks like yours is index.html, so that should be abobe hostingstart.html. See attached image.

[image]

EDIT:
Seems like this is a Linux app service since its missing the default documents. To solve this on Linux you should upload a index.js as described on https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#set-your-default-document-in-a-nodejs-app-using-javascriptapplies-to-azure-app-service-on-linuxapplies-to-web-app-for-containers

`var express = require('express'); var server = express(); var options = { index: 'index.html' }; server.use('/', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options)); server.listen(process.env.PORT);`

Comment: I don't have the default documents tab there. All I have is app settings, general settings and path mappings.

Comment: `Default documents` tab is avialable for windows based Azure Web App.

Comment: @ffffff01 - yes I did. It appears because its a linux machine it behaves a little bit differently. No IIS so I had to add the startup command `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`.